# Cutting typearea by brush / showing typearea in brush zone

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, brush

[image: My issue]

I would like to ask how, if its possible, to cut the orange font so it would be only inside the black area (made with brush) and the rest of the font on the white area would not be shown. Using Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Select black, area merge it to one shape with shape builder. Move it to front of everything. Select everything and choose **Object → Clipping Mask → Make...**.

If you want the area to stay back draw a black square behind everything. You can edit contents of clipping bask by selecting with black arrow tool and double clicking.

Comment: If the black shape is not one connected shapes but several disconnected shapes, you have to make them into a 'compound shape' before it is used to create a clipping mask. Also, make a copy of the black shape first because the clipping mask will become an invisible object.